# Detect NFC tag on Galaxy Watch 4 Classic (KSQW)

Tags: kotlin, nfc, wear-os, wearables

Hello I would like to create app in Kotlin that can work with NFC on wear os. So far app can detect whether device has NFC or is it on/off but now **I am stuck on trying to detect the tag** and displaying either toast or something in logs that there was connection. I attached how the project is structured as well as Detect.kt (that I think should be named MainActivity.kt), AndroidManifest.xml and NfcReceiver.kt

```
package com.example.detectnfc

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
class Detect : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    private var messageTextView: TextView? = null
    private var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
    private val nfcReceiver = NfcReceiver()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear)
        messageTextView = findViewById(R.id.messageTextView)

        Log.d("create", "created")

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // NFC is not available for this device
            Log.d("detect", "NFC not available")
            Toast.makeText(
                this, "NFC is not available on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            finish()
        } else if (!nfcAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            // NFC is available for the device but not enabled
            Log.d("detect", "NFC not enabled")
            Toast.makeText(
                this, "Turn on NFC in your device settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            finish()
        } else {
            // NFC is enabled, register the BroadcastReceiver
            Log.d("detect", "NFC enabled")
            val intentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
            registerReceiver(nfcReceiver, intentFilter)
        }

        // Create an Intent for the activity you want to launch
        val intent = Intent(this, this::class.java)

        // Set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

        // Create a PendingIntent
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Unregister the BroadcastReceiver when the activity is destroyed
        unregisterReceiver(nfcReceiver)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        if (intent != null && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
            // NFC tag detected, show a toast
            Log.d("detect", "Tag Detected")

            Toast.makeText(
                this, "Tag Detected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

            // You can add additional handling for the detected tag here if needed.
        }
    }
}
```

The NfcReceiver

```
package com.example.detectnfc

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

class NfcReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) {
            Log.d("NfcReceiver", "NFC tag detected")

            // Handle NFC tag detection here
            // You can perform actions or notify the Detect activity as needed
            Toast.makeText(
                context, "NFC Tag Detected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.detectnfc">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />
        <activity

            android:name="com.example.detectnfc.Detect"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:exported="true">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried to search for information but there are not that many articles about NFC specifically on smartwatches

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632775/how-to-use-nfc-actions as this code would not work on a normal Android Device, the NFC Intents are not broadcast intents. I would recommend method 3 `enableReaderMode` if your app is already running or Method 1 if you want to start your app by NFC but use NDEF or TECH Discovered not TAG as the system NFC App gets that before your App will. From the Android source Wear OS looks the same for NFC as a normal Android Device.